# How do I carry some data through Bluebirds .map?

Tags: node.js, promise, bluebird

I am using Blubird and Sequelize (which uses Blubird under the covers).

Suppose I have a code similar to:

```
Feed.findAll()
    .map(function (feed) { //  <---- this is what I'm interested in below
        // do some stuff here
        return some_promise_here;
    })
    .map(function (whatever) {
        // What is the best way to access feed here?
    })
    ....
```

I have found some replies which hinted at possible solutions, but I can't quite put my finger on it.

I have tried with `Promise.all()`, `.spread()`, but I never managed to make it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Feed.findAll()
    .map(function (feed) { //  <---- this is what I'm interested in below
        // do some stuff here
        return some_promise_here.then(function(result){
            return { result: result, feed: feed};// return everything you need for the next promise map below.
        });
    })
    .map(function (whatever) {
        // here you are dealing with the mapped results from the previous .map
        // whatever -> {result: [Object],feed:[Object]}
    })
```

Answer (score 2):

This looks very similar to [How do I access previous promise results in a .then() chain?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28250680/1048572), however you're dealing with a `.map` call here and seem to want to access the previous result for the same index of the processed array. In that case, not all solutions do apply, and a [closure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28250687/1048572) seems to be the simplest solution:

```
Feed.findAll().map(function (feed) { 
    // do some stuff here
    return some_promise_here.then(function (whatever) {
        // access `feed` here
    });
})
```

You can apply [explicit pass-through](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28250693/1048572) as well, though, like outlined in @bluetoft's answer.

Comment: I used a closure before, but I had a giant nested chain of promises and that's why I went with @bluetoft's answer. Thanks, yours certainly works as well!